# open-api-generator how to avoid fields being nullable

Tags: kotlin, openapi, openapi-generator

When I use the open-api-generator all of the fields are ? nullable, all classes look like this:

```
data class PagedResultDtoOfStoredDeviceFilterWithoutTermDto (

    @Json(name = "currentPage")
    val currentPage: kotlin.Int? = null,

    @Json(name = "totalPages")
    val totalPages: kotlin.Int? = null,

    @Json(name = "pageSize")
    val pageSize: kotlin.Int? = null,

    @Json(name = "totalCount")
    val totalCount: kotlin.Int? = null,

    @Json(name = "items")
    val items: kotlin.collections.List<StoredDeviceFilterWithoutTermDto>? = null

)
```

Despite many fields are NOT nullable server-side, as you can see in the [swagger.json](https://app-hsm-clse-stage.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html?urls.primaryName=Standard%20API) This makes the generator unusable to me, do somebody know why this happens?

This is my generator config:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate ^
     -g kotlin ^
     --library jvm-retrofit2 ^
     -i "https://app-hsm-clse-stage.azurewebsites.net/swagger/standardV1/swagger.json" ^
     -p groupId=com.mycompany ^
     -p artifactId=mycompany-myproduct-client-kotlin ^
     -p artifactVersion=1.0.0 ^
     -p basePackage=com.mycompany.myproduct.networking ^
     -p packageName=com.mycompany.myproduct.networking ^
     -p configPackage=com.mycompany.myproduct.networking.config ^
     -p apiPackage=com.mycompany.myproduct.networking.api ^
     -p modelPackage=com.mycompany.myproduct.networking.model ^
     -p sourceFolder=src/main/java ^
     -p dateLibrary=java8 ^
     -p java8=true ^
     -p useRxJava3=true ^
     
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially accomplish this using [templates](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/templating.md) and [extensions](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/templating.md#extensions).

Create a vendor extension called `x-is-nullable` and add it to your object schema.  I'm using your `AbsoluteDateIntervalDto` object as an example:

```yaml
    AbsoluteDateIntervalDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        startDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
          x-is-nullable: "false"
        endDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
          x-is-nullable: "false"
        startIncluded:
          type: boolean
          default: true
        endIncluded:
          type: boolean
      additionalProperties: false
```

Note that I added a default value to `startIncluded` to demonstrate how this works with default values as well.

now, change the template for `data_class_opt_var.mustache`.  Replace the last line so that it looks like this:

```
{{^vendorExtensions.x-is-nullable}}{{#multiplatform}}@SerialName(value = "{{{vendorExtensions.x-base-name-literal}}}") {{/multiplatform}}{{#isInherited}}override {{/isInherited}}{{>modelMutable}} {{{name}}}: {{#isArray}}{{#isList}}{{#uniqueItems}}kotlin.collections.{{#modelMutable}}Mutable{{/modelMutable}}Set{{/uniqueItems}}{{^uniqueItems}}kotlin.collections.{{#modelMutable}}Mutable{{/modelMutable}}List{{/uniqueItems}}{{/isList}}{{^isList}}kotlin.Array{{/isList}}<{{^items.isEnum}}{{^items.isPrimitiveType}}{{^items.isModel}}{{#kotlinx_serialization}}@Contextual {{/kotlinx_serialization}}{{/items.isModel}}{{/items.isPrimitiveType}}{{{items.dataType}}}{{/items.isEnum}}{{#items.isEnum}}{{classname}}.{{{nameInCamelCase}}}{{/items.isEnum}}>{{/isArray}}{{^isEnum}}{{^isArray}}{{{dataType}}}{{/isArray}}{{/isEnum}}{{#isEnum}}{{^isArray}}{{classname}}.{{{nameInCamelCase}}}{{/isArray}}{{/isEnum}}? = {{^defaultValue}}null{{/defaultValue}}{{#defaultValue}}{{^isNumber}}{{{defaultValue}}}{{/isNumber}}{{#isNumber}}{{^multiplatform}}{{{dataType}}}("{{{defaultValue}}}"){{/multiplatform}}{{#multiplatform}}({{{defaultValue}}}).toDouble(){{/multiplatform}}{{/isNumber}}{{/defaultValue}}{{/vendorExtensions.x-is-nullable}}{{#vendorExtensions.x-is-nullable}}{{#multiplatform}}@SerialName(value = "{{{vendorExtensions.x-base-name-literal}}}") {{/multiplatform}}{{#isInherited}}override {{/isInherited}}{{>modelMutable}} {{{name}}}: {{#isArray}}{{#isList}}{{#uniqueItems}}kotlin.collections.{{#modelMutable}}Mutable{{/modelMutable}}Set{{/uniqueItems}}{{^uniqueItems}}kotlin.collections.{{#modelMutable}}Mutable{{/modelMutable}}List{{/uniqueItems}}{{/isList}}{{^isList}}kotlin.Array{{/isList}}<{{^items.isEnum}}{{^items.isPrimitiveType}}{{^items.isModel}}{{#kotlinx_serialization}}@Contextual {{/kotlinx_serialization}}{{/items.isModel}}{{/items.isPrimitiveType}}{{{items.dataType}}}{{/items.isEnum}}{{#items.isEnum}}{{classname}}.{{{nameInCamelCase}}}{{/items.isEnum}}>{{/isArray}}{{^isEnum}}{{^isArray}}{{{dataType}}}{{/isArray}}{{/isEnum}}{{#isEnum}}{{^isArray}}{{classname}}.{{{nameInCamelCase}}}{{/isArray}}{{/isEnum}}{{#defaultValue}} = {{^isNumber}}{{{defaultValue}}}{{/isNumber}}{{#isNumber}}{{^multiplatform}}{{{dataType}}}("{{{defaultValue}}}"){{/multiplatform}}{{#multiplatform}}({{{defaultValue}}}).toDouble(){{/multiplatform}}{{/isNumber}}{{/defaultValue}}{{/vendorExtensions.x-is-nullable}}
```

Note:  this is a very long line, however it must all be on one line for it to work correctly.

Here's how it works.  The `open-api generator` will put all vendor extensions into an array called `vendorExtensions` that is accessible to the mustache templating engine.  The line `{{^vendorExtensions.x-is-nullable}}` checks to see if the `x-is-nullable` extension exists in the array.  the carrot(`^`) is basically equals to `if (x-is-nullable.doesNotExist())`.  The value `false` assigned in the preceding yaml is arbitrary.  You can have any value you want there, but a value must exist.

Now the template will execute all of the code between the `{{^vendorExtensions.x-is-nullable}}` and the closing `{{/vendorExtensions.x-is-nullable}}` if the vendor extension doesn't exist, and it will execute all the code between `{{#vendorExtensions.x-is-nullable}}{{/vendorExtensions.x-is-nullable}}` if it does.  This allows two different generations to occur in the same class.

Your new resulting data class from the above template change, using the above schema, will now look like this

```kotlin
data class AbsoluteDateIntervalDto (

    @Json(name = "startDate")
    val startDate: java.time.OffsetDateTime,

    @Json(name = "endDate")
    val endDate: java.time.OffsetDateTime,

    @Json(name = "startIncluded")
    val startIncluded: kotlin.Boolean = true,

    @Json(name = "endIncluded")
    val endIncluded: kotlin.Boolean? = null

)
```

Comment: Amazing! I wonder if this is a open-api-generator bug though, because it's not a special case to need so much knolwdge to achieve something that each one using the generator needs.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug so much as an un-implemented feature.  There are a lot of features that exist for some generators, but not for others.  For example, the [Java Spring generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md) has an option for `useOptional` and `OpenAPINullable` that you can toggle on and off.  The [Typescript Angular generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/typescript-angular.md) has a `enumPropertyNaming` option to set how enums are named.  These features don't exist elsewhere.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the "required" option in the schema though?